# postgreSQL: Trying to filter out duplicate rows where the same location is showing but the timestamps slightly differ?

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, timestamp

I'm using a dataset with fields "virtual_time" and "store_visited" and the data shows a user's activity pattern at different locations during different timestamps.

Problem is sometimes the user could be at the same location but there are several different records of the same place updated on the dataset with slightly different timestamps.

I'm trying to sort of I guess group those smaller timestamps together per location so the data makes better sense to me and I can later distinguish how much time that user has spent at each place.

For instance when I type:

```
SELECT DISTINCT virtual_time, store_visited
FROM public.consumer
WHERE user = 'e63a9'
ORDER BY 1;
```

I get back something like:

```
    Store_visited   virtual_time
  1 M&S          2017-09-16 17:52:06
  2 WholeFoods   2017-09-16 18:26:17
  3 WholeFoods   2017-09-16 18:26:19
  4 WholeFoods   2017-09-16 18:26:20
  5 OysterRooms  2017-09-18 13:31:39
```

But I'd like to filter out the duplicate stores visited from rows 3,4, as they show the same location with only show a time difference of like 2 seconds and 1 second.

Ideally filtering it would show something like:

```
    Store_visited   virtual_time
   1 M&S          2017-09-16 17:52:06
   2 WholeFoods   2017-09-16 18:26:17
   5 OysterRooms  2017-09-18 13:31:39
```

So that it's easier to distinguish the different timestamps at different stores.

Hope that make some sense. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

If you have any questions, please let me know!

Many thanks

Comment: This is a derived gaps and islands problem, for anyone thinking to attempt an answer.

Comment: I don't think I can clearly understand: "But I'd like to filter out the duplicate stores visited from rows 3,4, as they show the same location with only show a time difference of like 2 seconds and 1 second" because what you described in output is could be done with just: `SELECT MIN(virtual_time), store_visited FROM public.consumer ... GROUP BY stored_visited`

Answer (score 1):

You could round the timestamps to minutes:

```
select distinct store_visited, date_trunc('minute', virtual_time) as virtual_time
from consumer
order by 2;
```

This is the fastest but not very accurate solution. A better one is to check differences between consecutive rows and skip those which fall within a specific range. Use the [window function lag():](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-window.html)

```
select store_visited, virtual_time
from (
    select 
        store_visited, virtual_time, 
        coalesce(virtual_time- lag(virtual_time) over w < '10 seconds', false) as neglible
    from consumer
    window w as (partition by store_visited order by virtual_time)
    ) s
where not neglible
order by 2;  

 store_visited |    virtual_time     
---------------+---------------------
 M&S           | 2017-09-16 17:52:06
 WholeFoods    | 2017-09-16 18:26:17
 OysterRooms   | 2017-09-18 13:31:39
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is gasp and islands problem. You can solve this by using [`Row_Number Function`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)

From Documentation :

> number of the current row within its partition, counting from 1

```
select
    store_visited,
    virtual_time
from
    (select 
          store_visited, 
          virtual_time, 
          row_number() over(partition by store_visited order by virtual_time asc) as vt
      from
          tbl) as new
where
    vt = '1'
order by
    virtual_time;
```

For [*Demo<>Fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c23c10050af3361fab2150425cec9d64)